# Output of a program. Test type of questions

Tags: java, output, superclass

could someone explain to me why the output is "DDAC" and not "DAC"? Why it prints "D" two times?

```
class A {
    String text = "A";
    String getText(){
        return text;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println((new B()).getText());
    }
}
class B extends A{
     B(){
         text = getText() + "C";
     }
     String getText(){
         return  "D" + super.getText();
     }
}
```

Comment: Run it in your **debugger**.

Comment: You should step through with a debugger.

Comment: Once you realize that `B`'s `getText` is called twice, the "mystery" should be solved for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is confusing because you have two methods in different classes with the same name. You called `getText()` in your constructor `B()`, which was getting the text from class B. You wanted it to get text from class A.  All I did was change the name of `getText()` in class B to `getBText()`, and called the methods correctly. Code shown below:

```
class ScratchPaper {
    String text = "A";
    String getText(){
        return text;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println((new B()).getBText());
    }
}
class B extends ScratchPaper {
     B(){
         text = getText() + "C";
     }
     String getBText(){
         return  "D" + super.getText();
     }
}
```

And the output is how you expected:

```
DAC
```

Answer (score 2):

In the code, if you see when

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println((new B()).getText());
}
```

is called first, the constructor of B is called that is

```
B(){
     text = getText() + "C";
 }
```

here if you see the attribute text is inherited from the superclass A
So, when the constructor is called

```
 B(){
     text = getText() + "C";
 }
 String getBText(){
     return  "D" + super.getText();
 }
```

the value of text which is an attribute of the superclass get value 'DAC'

```
text = "DAC";
```

Now when B's instance is created and then once again getText() of B is called

```
**(new B()).getText()**
```

which calls the below code

```
String getBText(){
 return  "D" + super.getText(); // here super.getText() = "DAC"
}
```

which prints "DDAC" !!!

Comment: I just explained the text attribute of the superclass is getting modified in the constructor of the subclass, which is causing printing of D twice